# Can I make a virtual PC part of a domain?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am using Oracle Virtual Box and have made a server (fardomain.local) this server has active directory on it and completely set up. I then made a normal machine in Oracle Virtual Box.
What I was wondering is if I can make the Virtual machine part of the fardomain? And if so, does anyone know how I can do so?
Thank-you,
Fern

Comment: What is a normal VM? You mentioned Active Directory so you have set up a Windows Server, if the normal VM is a Windows Client OS then just add it in e.g. Control Panel\System and Security\System. Assuming the Server and Client VM have network connectivity.

Comment: If the VM can see the domain, then it can join the domain, only a matter of the VM being added to the domain by the Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The VM should be joined as usual without any kind of problem.
Just check your VM is in the same IP range as the domain controller (because sometimes VirtualBox configures the VM network as 'NAT'instead as 'bridge' which is what you need to be in the same IP range).
Regards